# como remover nós de um arquivo xml com javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Eu tenho um documento xml,um script.js e uma página html onde deve ocorrer o seguinte teste,eu clico em um botão na página e deverá ser executada uma função no script que remove um grupo de nós do arquivo xml,segue ele abaixo

```
FILE.XML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<filmes>
<filme>
  <titulo>A Casa Branca</titulo>
  <genero>comédia</genero>
  <ano>1999</ano>
  <faixaEtaria>+10</faixaEtaria>
</filme>
<filme>
  <titulo>A casa monstro</titulo>
  <genero>animação</genero>
  <ano>2007</ano>
  <faixaEtaria>+10</faixaEtaria>
</filme>
<filme>
  <titulo>O grito</titulo>
  <genero>terror/suspense</genero>
  <ano>2003</ano>
  <faixaEtaria>+14</faixaEtaria>
</filme>
<filme>
  <titulo>Pânico</titulo>
  <genero>suspense</genero>
  <ano>2006</ano>
  <faixaEtaria>+14</faixaEtaria>
</filme>
</filmes>
```

E quando eu clicar no botão da página,ele deve remover o primeiro grupo de nós do nó filme,consequentemente vai o código vai ficar assim

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<filmes>
  <titulo>A casa monstro</titulo>
  <genero>animação</genero>
  <ano>2007</ano>
  <faixaEtaria>+10</faixaEtaria>
</filme>
<filme>
  <titulo>O grito</titulo>
  <genero>terror/suspense</genero>
  <ano>2003</ano>
  <faixaEtaria>+14</faixaEtaria>
</filme>
<filme>
  <titulo>Pânico</titulo>
  <genero>suspense</genero>
  <ano>2006</ano>
  <faixaEtaria>+14</faixaEtaria>
</filme>
</filmes>
```

Eu já pesquisei sobre o removeChild mas não consigo criar uma função que remova os nós do arquivo xml,preciso muito de ajuda pois não encontro solucões pra isso,então qualquer exemplo de função que resolva o problema já será bem útil.

Comment: Vc quer remover do arquivo ou da leitura? Digo, regravar o arquivo sem o nó ou apenas ler e remover o nó?

Comment: do arquivo,ele serve como um armazenador de dados no meu projeto

Comment: ou seja,regravar o arquivo sem o nó

Comment: Vc usa PHP?......

Comment: uso,porém estou criando um aplicativo móvel híbrido e preciso usar funções do JS,o app vai buscar dados do arquivo xml.

Comment: Para reescrever o arquivo vc precisa usar uma linguagem do lado do servidor, como PHP.

Comment: Ok,mas e com JSON?É possível eu alterar e remover valores no código json com javascript?

Comment: Sim, é possível.

Comment: Entendi,obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer desse jeito:

```
y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("filme")[0];

xmlDoc.documentElement.removeChild(y);
```

Para remover o primeiro filme da sua lista.

Fonte: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodes_remove.asp

Comment: O removeChild eu já tentei,mas ele só remove o que está na tela e não do arquivo xml